# Using WeakSubscribe from MvvmCross

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I need to subscribe to `INotifyPropertyChanged` of one of my models in my ViewModel. My research led me to: [How do I update the parent viewmodel when child viewmodel is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405470/how-do-i-update-the-parent-viewmodel-when-child-viewmodel-is-updated/18408578#18408578).

I tried using `WeakSubscribe` as suggested in #3 but after entering and leaving the view several times my whole application either freezes or crashes.

Here's my code from `Init()` in the ViewModel:

```cs
        foreach (var sale in Model.Sales)
        {
            sale.WeakSubscribe(delegate
            {
                Model.CalculateSalesTotals();
            });
        }
```

when the app is crashing, I'm getting `SIGSEGV`:

```
I/mono-stdout(30334): mvx:Diagnostic:227.00 Showing ViewModel InvoiceAuthorizationViewModel
I/ActivityManager(  391): START u0 {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.desco.escMobile/escmobile.android.views.InvoiceAuthorizationView (has extras)} from pid 30334
I/mono-stdout(30334): mvx:Diagnostic:227.19 Loading new ViewModel from Intent with Extras
D/dalvikvm(30334): GC_EXPLICIT freed 783K, 5% free 17252K/18068K, paused 2ms+8ms, total 53ms
I/mono-stdout(30334): MvxBind:Warning:227.59 Unable to bind: source property source not found Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.PropertyPath.PropertyTokens.MvxPr
opertyNamePropertyToken on null-object
I/mono-stdout(30334): MvxBind:Warning:227.61 Unable to bind: source property source not found Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.PropertyPath.PropertyTokens.MvxPr
opertyNamePropertyToken on null-object
I/mono-stdout(30334): MvxBind:Warning:227.63 Unable to bind: source property source not found Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Parse.PropertyPath.PropertyTokens.MvxPr
opertyNamePropertyToken on null-object
I/dalvikvm(30334): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
I/ActivityManager(  391): Displayed com.desco.escMobile/escmobile.android.views.InvoiceAuthorizationView: +755ms (total +1s259ms)
I/ActivityManager(  391): Displayed com.desco.escMobile/escmobile.android.views.InvoiceAuthorizationView: +1s279ms
I/ActivityManager(  391): Process com.android.vending (pid 30179) has died.
E/mono-rt (30334): Stacktrace:
E/mono-rt (30334):
E/mono-rt (30334):
E/mono-rt (30334): =================================================================
E/mono-rt (30334): Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
E/mono-rt (30334): a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
E/mono-rt (30334): used by your application.
E/mono-rt (30334): =================================================================
E/mono-rt (30334):
I/ActivityManager(  391): Process com.desco.escMobile (pid 30334) has died.
I/WindowState(  391): WIN DEATH: Window{42cf2e60 u0 com.desco.escMobile/escmobile.android.views.InvoiceAuthorizationView}
W/ActivityManager(  391): Force removing ActivityRecord{42e05b20 u0 com.desco.escMobile/escmobile.android.views.InvoiceAuthorizationView}: app died, no saved st
ate
I/WindowState(  391): WIN DEATH: Window{427bfbf0 u0 com.desco.escMobile/escmobile.android.views.DispatchListView}
I/WindowState(  391): WIN DEATH: Window{42b32b50 u0 com.desco.escMobile/escmobile.android.views.InvoiceDetailsView}
I/WindowState(  391): WIN DEATH: Window{43003e48 u0 com.desco.escMobile/escmobile.android.views.InvoiceAuthorizationView}
I/WindowState(  391): WIN DEATH: Window{42aea920 u0 com.desco.escMobile/escmobile.android.views.DispatchDetailsView}
D/dalvikvm(30434): Late-enabling CheckJNI
I/ActivityManager(  391): Start proc com.desco.escMobile for activity com.desco.escMobile/escmobile.android.views.InvoiceAuthorizationView: pid=30434 uid=10086
gids={50086, 3003, 1015, 1028}
D/Zygote  (  129): Process 30334 exited cleanly (255)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: My main suggestion would be to focus on identifying which line or lines are causing this crash, and to then think of this at quite a low level issue. This is `a SIGSEGV while executing native code` so I suspect that focussing on `Using WeakSubscribe from MvvmCross` won't get you very far. Other than that, no other thoughts or suggestions.

Comment: Stuart, if I don't use WeakSubscribe, and instead subscribe to the event directly and in my view call a method of ViewModel to unsubscribed when leaving the screen - everything works well. No freezes. No crashes.

Comment: You are saying that `WeakSubscribe` causes the crash - which might be true. Or it might be that if you strong reference things, then it doesn't dispose or garbage collect something, and as a result it doesn't crash... As before, my main suggestion is to focus on identifying what is actually causing the crash - from the detail posted all I can tell is `a SIGSEGV while executing native code` - and that suggests looking low level to me. Regardless, good luck!