# How to communicate between viewmodels (master <--> detail) in mvvmcross

Tags: c#, android, viewmodel, mvvmcross

I am writing to enquire about an implementation detail for MVVX (android):
Imaging an order activity, with a number of order lines:

```
LineNo  Desc.          Qty    U/P    S/Total
1.      Ketchup          2    $1.00    $2.00    [+] [-]
2.      French Fries     1    $4.00    $4.00    [+] [-]
                           Sub-Total   $6.00
                                 VAT   ...
                               Total   ...
```

The [+] and [-] buttons will increment/decrement the quantity respectively. These buttons are on the detail viewmodel (listview item).

Now the thing is that each line item is mapped to its viewmodel, and the order has its own viewmodel. How do I communicate from the line item VM to the order VM? I need to get updates in the order VM in order to calculate the subtotal, VAT and total.

Based on the samples I’ve seen I can use MvxMessenger (the order line fires a message that is grabbed by the order). Is this the best method for my scenario?

Comment: I would imagine it's all the same screen. So you Master VM has a list of detail VM's, but the detail VM's never get navigated to? Is that correct?

Comment: @Ross No we are talking about two different screens/activities, the master activity and the listitem activity. The [+] and [-] sign are on the listitem activity.
I am not sure how to do it in a single activity, is there any sample in the mvvmx tutorials?

Comment: I guess this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405470/how-do-i-update-the-parent-viewmodel-when-child-viewmodel-is-updated?rq=1 answers my question. I just wanted to know if there were better alternatives.